# Upgrading to Embe-cli@2.7.0 killed ember test -s for browsers

Tags: phantomjs, ember-cli, testem

After upgrading an ember project to ember-cli@2.7.0 I stumbled upon  problem of getting

```
$ ember test -s
```

work with my test browsers again (Chromium, Firefox).

Only PhantomJS was launched, no matter how I did set up config file `testem.js`

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there are 2 testem-related config files after the upgrade:

- testem.js
- testem.json

Removing the latter one (**testem.json**) made it work again.